# Freemarker compress single_line without spaces

Tags: java, freemarker

It seems that <@compress single_line=true> is replacing line breaks with single spaces (" "), instead of just suppressing them.

Example:

```
<@compress single_line=true>
"First cell"
<#if something >
    |"Second cell"
</#if>
|"Third cell"
</@compress>
```

Is printing:

```
"First cell" |"Second cell" |"Third cell"
```

Which can't be parsed by a legacy system just because of the spaces between the pipes.

Is there any way to avoid this?, perhaps a way to read every "nested" line in a macro to substitute the functionality of @compress?

In the end, I don't want "structural source code", but presentation code, so assigning to variables to just print the result won't be nice.

Thank you in advance, kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@compress` doesn't completely remove whitespace-regions because that would change the meaning of the output in almost all applications. `@compress` itself is technically just a custom directive (that's why it uses `@` instead of `#`). Only it's always there for backward compatibility... So, yes, you can implement filters like that. You could implement `TemplateDirectiveModel` (where you can use your own `Writer` implementation to do the filtering) then drop it into the data-model, like, with name `myCompress`. Or you can pull it into the template like `#assign myCompress = 'com.example.MyCompressDirective'?new`, wherever you would use `#macro`. In both cases, you could use it like `<@myCompress>...</@myCompress>`.

Actually, you can solve this with a macro too. You can capture the generated output inside the macro with `<#local captured><#nested></#local>`, then use regular expressions with `?replace` and such. It's just kind of ugly... filtering fits Java better. (Note that if the `output_format` of the defining template is `HTML`, `XML`, etc., then you will need something like `captured?markup_string?replace(...)?no_esc`. That is, you have to convert the captured markup to plain string, do the modifications on that, then convert it back to markup again.)

Note that you can also solve compression outside the template, if you pass a custom compressing `Writer` to `Template.process`.

Comment: Yesss... thank you so much. `<#local captured><#nested></#local>` with regular expressions is what better suits my needs, why?, becuase if I can deliver my solution without custom java code it means that a System Administrator will be able to edit the template without need of I to recompile, if requirements change in a near future. How can I upvote more than once your answer?, I appreciate the Java-side solutions too to better understand Freemarker architecture, I'll check it out deeper. Kind regards.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to @ddekany to answer this question. Next is the simple code that trims:

1. Leading spaces (^\s+)
2. Trailing spaces (\s+$)
3. Line breaks (\n|\r)

Using regular expressions in multi-line mode ("rm" parameter)

You just need to remove any element on the expression to suit your needs, for example, if you just want to remove indentation, don't use 2 and 3 ;)

```
<#macro compress_single_line>
    <#local captured><#nested></#local>
${ captured?replace("^\\s+|\\s+$|\\n|\\r", "", "rm") }
</#macro>
<@compress_single_line>

    My free indented content    

        ${ someVar }

</@compress_single_line>
```

Hope this complements helpfully @ddekany's answer.

Comment: Thanks - that helped me create this similar macro (needs to be on one line):

<#macro compress_empty_lines><#local captured><#nested></#local>${ captured?replace("^\\s*[\\n\\r]+", "", "rmg") }</#macro>

Comment: Some extra steps are needed if the macro is defined in a template that uses an escaping `output_format`, like `HTML` or `XML`, as then the captured value won't be a string but "markup output". I have added the relevant information to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works also fine:

```
<#assign var>
"First cell"
<#if something >
    |"Second cell"
</#if>
|"Third cell"
</#assign>
${var?replace("^\\s+|\\s+$|\\n|\\r", "", "rm")}
```